# PHP: connecting to available remote db, retriving data from db and filling that data in an html form, and print form data as pdf

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2005, tcpdf

I have created an html form with over 20 fields and want to print data from the form a page or pdf for printout using php.

But most of the field data is available in a sql server 2005 database already available to me. But I'm not able to access this database. And I need to access it. Once I access the database, I need to use data entered into my 'id' & 'date' field to retrieve data from the db as that 'id' and 'date'.(Example Query: Select * from tablename where id="123" and date="12/08/2012" ;  or something like that) After that I need to push this data into their relevant fields in my html form. And once i click submit after all this is entered. I need it to display all this information as a table in the browser or as a pdf, so i can print it out. I read up on tcpdf but can't make head otr tail of it. Hope you can help.

Can anyone help me with this?

Keep in mind that I'm new to coding and php and databases. I have a little experience with html. But I'm not great with advanced stuff.

I would love it if u could answer me with a sample program similar to mine with all the necessary elements. Thank You in advance! I hope I'm not asking for too much.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>TEST PHP DB</title>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_POST=""))
        {
            $mydb="OASIS";
            $conn=mssql_connect("Server", "admin", "password") or die ("Error in Connection");
            $select=mssql_select_db($mydb,$conn) or die("Couldn't connect to db");

            $pid=$_POST("ID");        
            $strSQL = "SELECT [First Name] FROM [Data Table] where Patient='$pid'";
            $rs = mssql_query($strSQL);

            while($row = mssql_fetch_array($rs)) 
            {
                echo $row["First Name"];
            }

            if (!$strSQL) 
            {
                die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
            }

            mssql_close($conn);
        }
        ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="test" method="POST">
            ID : <input name="ID" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
            NAME : <input name="FirstName" type="text">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, your question is a bit confusing - the data in SQL Server is available to you but you cannot access them? like you have them stored outside somewhere but cannot access the DB directly you mean?

Comment: i cant access them, in the sense that i'm not able to access the database throught th php code i was trying to implement. Is it clear now?

Comment: and the databse is on a server in my office. but not on my own system.

Comment: yes, it's clear now, thank you... so you need to be able to access the database via PHP code as far as I can tell - did you try [mssql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php) in PHP?

Comment: yes, i did..

This is what i tried..

$conn=mssql_connect("Server", "admin", "password") or die ("Error in Connection");

$select=mssql_select_db("OASIS",$conn) or die("Couldn't connect to db");

Comment: so what was the result? you should be able to use mssql_get_last_message() function to display error messages if PHP cannot connect

Comment: well, this was coded in the head part of an html form. and was suposed to display the retrieved data when i clicked submit...but nothing happened..i entered the required data..and clicked submit..and nothing happened..
but lemme try mssql_get_last_message()...

Comment: Ok, i tried it...And it still is the same..!

Comment: if there is no message, it's probable that the code is not executing at all - try moving that database stuff to the top of page, loading it once the page loads (not dependent on form submit) and see if that fetches any data for you

Comment: Done. Please examine the code and let me know what's wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$mydb="OASIS";
echo $mydb;

$conn=mssql_connect("Server", "admin", "password") or die ("Error in Connection");
// this is only for debug purposes:
echo mssql_get_last_message();

$select=mssql_select_db($mydb,$conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());

$pid=$_POST("ID");


$strSQL = "SELECT [First Name] FROM [Data Table] where Patient='$pid'";


$rs = mssql_query($strSQL);
// this is only for debug purposes:
echo mssql_get_last_message();


while($row = mssql_fetch_array($rs)) 
{

  echo $row["First Name"];

}

if (!$strSQL) 
{

        die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

mssql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work..! :(
If the server is remote do I have to change the server name or give an exteded path..I'm not sure if it is...but if i have to change it..then i'll ask my superiors..

Comment: please include what errors / messages / output you experience when you say it doesn't work as well... as for the server URL, that's something you need to know - best if it can be an IP address, so no additional DNS resolving is done when you use like "http://www.mypage.com:1234"

Comment: it is not showing me any errors when i view in browser..tht's y i'm confused..!

Comment: ok, that could mean the connection is OK - try doing var_dump($conn); and var_dump($rs); respectively to see whether they output a connection object or not - if they do, it means nothing matches your selection, so you can echo out your $strSQL and try that directly on the server - if it doesn't return any values either, you're all set and only need to post data (I guess $pid is empty now, that's why nothing is being selected)

Comment: according to my superioirs..the tables are already populated...:/
but i tried var_dump() in my php code..! nothing..!
Also tried to echo out $strSQL...still the same..
Could it be some browser settings that i need to change?

Comment: I've updated the code, try it and see if it at least prints out the initial echo... if not, then the problem is either with the server or perhaps you're not copying the file where you think you are

Comment: nope..even the first echo isn't working...when i view it in the browser...all i can see are the form fields and the submit button...and nothing happens if i enter a value and click submit..:/

Is it possible for u to write a new example code for me including the html for elements? And if that doesn't work on the server, then it must be some error there..

Comment: it's easy to do so for you - just visit the .php page with this code I posted directly - don't post from another page, just go to yourpage.php and see what it does for you

Comment: how can u post from another page? I'm directly editing my php file.

Comment: so you created a file like mypage.php, put my code in it and run it? and it shows nothing? posting from another page would be to include an "action" attribute in your form, pointing to the external page - so a form in index.html file would have action attribute of mypage.php

Comment: i created a page and inserted your code and ran it..I dint kno i had to load it into my wamp www folder..anyway, even then it runs oly the first echo...and after that it shows "Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" error...What do you think is wrong?

Comment: you don't have mssql extension enabled in your wamp - [check this guide](http://forum.ragezone.com/f724/get-wamp-work-mssql-673301/) to see how to enable it

Comment: followed the guide..and did everything as it said..it doesnt work...i had already had ntwdblib.dll in my apache folder...so i jus had to add it to the php folder..and my wamp has php 5.4.3..but i dont think it should matter...Does the code change if I'm working with SQL server 2005? cuz i saw some sites where they have use 'sqlsrv' instead of 'mssql' in the code..:/

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with wamp, you'll need to either ask another question or Google this for yourself

Answer (score 0):

well for the first part you need to have `SQL Server drivers` and you can establish connection between php and SQL Server. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html) for more information.

For the second part, it is very simple, you need to implement `AJAX` on your site. Once id and date has been entered an AJAX call must be made to the server to do the necessary querying and the result can be displayed in the rest of the fields. This is a [tutorial](http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/) on AJAX and PHP that achieves form autofilling dynamically from a MySql database.

To convert your HTML to PHP take a look at this [example](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Use-PHP-to-Create-Dynamic-pdf-Files/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: do i have to use AJAX? I'm afraid if it'll take me too long to pick up..!

Comment: no you do not. Although it is the neatest solution for the user experience, it is not necessary. Concentrate on the html/php part first. When everything works, step up a level and learn javascript. Only after that start with ajax (ajax is actually a technique for javascript).

Comment: otherwise it'll be more like loading a new page which is bad user experience. and what you want it rather simple. shouldnt take much time to figure out.

Comment: could you help out with some kind of sample code i can apply on my page?

Comment: i changed the link in the above answer. do take a look. It does almost exactly what you want.